# How to write parquet files to elastic search with dynamic index and type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I want to write dataframes from parquet files to elastic search and I want to create index and types from values of dataframes dyanamically.

my dataframe is

```
timestamp                country    data
2017-08-16 00:00:00      india      xyz
2017-08-16 00:00:00      US         xyz
```

I have following code to write this to ES

```
features.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .option("es.resource","timestamp/country").save()
```

but this is not working as I expect

This creates an index "`timestamp`" and a type "`country`"

However I want to create index as "`2017-08-16 00:00:00`" and two types "`india`" and "`US`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out

```
import org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark
```

with `saveToEs` method. For detailed information please [refer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html)

```
val game = Map("type"->"game","title" -> "FF VI","year" -> "1994")
val book = Map("type" -> "book","title" -> "Harry Potter","year" -> "2010")
val cd = Map("type" -> "music","title" -> "Surfing With The Alien")

sc.makeRDD(Seq(game, book, cd)).saveToEs("index/{type}")
```

Comment: what about aligning you with added approach ?